# Understanding TestDisk behaviour on disappeared files from a git / docker folder

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, git, testdisk

I have totally messed up a git / docker local folder, and some of my files (curiously only those which were not tracked by git) have suddenly disappeared from one data subfolder ; I cannot see them anymore either with nautilus, or also from a terminal. It may be due to a wrong manipulation within the containerized application as it has root access, but I can unfortunately not remember when exactly this happened.

Hence I get my hands back on this marvelous tool called [TestDisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_FR) in order to see if I cant get them back.

And as you can see here https://www.tecmint.com/recover-deleted-files-using-testdisk-in-linux/ red entries are deleted files.

The problem I am facing is that in my TestDisk, I can see old files that I have effectively deleted long ago in red, but the files that have disappeared in my git folder are not display in red, but in light gray, as any other usual existing files. The only red entry for these files is their parent folder.

On the following image, you can see at the bottom the 3 regular files which get deleted, that's OK. But the `data` folder still exists (gray entry on the image) but that folder is actually empty when I browse it with either nautilus, the terminal and TestDisk (and it definitively should not be empty)!

On the other hand, there is a second entry for the same `data` folder (heck, why?) in red, and if I browse in this red `data` folder within TestDisk, I can see my disappeared files. Where I'm really surprised, is that they are displayed in light gray, not in red! But they do not exist anymore on the disk!

[image: TestDisk screenshot]
**TestDisk [Advanced] > [List] menu.**

If anyone has a Cartesian explanation on this phenomena I would be glad to ear it.

ps; I've checkout all my git branches to see if the disappeared files are there (in case I've messed up things between branches) but it's not the case; they exist in none of the branches.

I am on a Ubuntu 18.04, ext4 file system.